# регулярное выражение для email

Tags: php

Почему, после обработки, емайлы не становятся ссылками?

```
<?php
    $text = "Привет от somebody@mail.ru, а также от other@mail.ru";

    $html = preg_replace(
        '/(\s+)@([a-z0-9.]+)/is',
        '<a href="mailto:$0">$0</a>',
        $text
    );

    echo $html;
?>
```

Comment: Лучшая тема - http://emailregex.com/

Comment: @AGS17, очень устаревшая информация по вашей ссылке.

Comment: вам поиска https://ru.stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5B%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%B3%D1%83%D0%BB%D1%8F%D1%80%D0%BD%D1%8B%D0%B5-%D0%B2%D1%8B%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%B6%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D1%8F%5D++email не хватило совсем?

Answer (score 0):

Регулярное выражение не верно у вас, попробуйте использовать другое, могу посоветовать свое:

```
$text = "Привет от somebody@mail.ru, а также от other@mail.ru";

$html = preg_replace(
    '/[A-Z0-9._%+-]+@[A-Z0-9.-]+\.[A-Z]{2,}/i',
    '<a href="mailto:$0">$0</a>',
    $text
);

echo $html;
```

Comment: а разве в доменах нельзя дефисы, цифры ?..

Comment: Можно конечно, подчеркивания нельзя

Comment: Домены могут быть других языков.

Comment: @YaroslavMolchan это я неправильно прочитал regex :)

Comment: Это из учебника Котерова, страница 382